What Are the Alternatives in Getting A Firebase User's ID Token If Calling "getIdToken()" Does not Work?
Problem
I am implementing a custom app check provider for my firebase android application using Java. The documentation for that can be found here.
I would like to retrieve the ID Token of the logged in user to send in the Authorization header in my http request to my Firebase Cloud Function in order to get an App Check Token. The issue arises when I call getIDToken() which never completes and does not execute the code in the onCompleteListener. Is there an alternative way to get the User's Id Token?
FirebaseAppCheckProvider.class
package com.example.data;

public class FirebaseAppCheckProvider implements AppCheckProvider {

    private RecaptchaTasksClient mRecaptchaTasksClient;

    public FirebaseAppCheckProvider(RecaptchaTasksClient pRecaptchaTasksClient) {
        mRecaptchaTasksClient = pRecaptchaTasksClient;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Task<AppCheckToken> getToken() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        TaskCompletionSource<AppCheckToken> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<AppCheckToken>();

        if (user != null) {
            user.getIdToken(true).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                    //never gets here
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String userTokenId = task.getResult().getToken();
                        Log.i("UserIDToken", "ID Token: " + userTokenId);
                        //Rest of code....
                        //set the taskCompletions to the result of the acquired app check
                        //token
                        taskCompletionSource.setResult(new FirebaseCustomAppCheckToken(appCheckToken,calculatedExp));
                        
                    } else {
                        Log.i("UserTokenID", "Error: " + task.getException());
                        taskCompletionSource.setResult(new FirebaseCustomAppCheckToken(null,0));
                    }


                }
            });
        }else
        {
            taskCompletionSource.setResult(new FirebaseCustomAppCheckToken(null,0));
        }


        return taskCompletionSource.getTask();

    }
}


